# Pass a function pointer as an argument between classes

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

How can we pass a function pointer as an argument? For example, the function pointer `myFunPtr` is an argument when calling class `A`  and I need this pointer to point to function `funcB` in class `B`

```
 #include <iostream>


typedef void(*myFunPtr)(void);

class A {
public:
    A(myFunPtr ptr);
    virtual ~A();
    myFunPtr funptr;
};

A::A(myFunPtr ptr){
    std::cout << "Constructor A \n";
    funptr = ptr;
}

A::~A(){}

 
///////////////
class B {
public:
    B();
    virtual ~B();
    void funcB();
};

B::B(){
    std::cout << "Constructor B \n";
    A *objA = new A(funcB);
}

B::~B(){}

void B::funcB(){
    std::cout << " call B::funcB \n";
}

///////////////

int main(){
     B *objB = new B();
     delete objB;
        
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a function pointer type to a free function (not a class member function):

```
typedef void(*myFunPtr)(void);
```

This is a `B` member function pointer type:

```
typedef void(B::*myFunPtr)(void);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5qanbb)

Here's another [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b17ojb) that will call a member function in a `B`. To do that, a pointer to a `B` and a pointer to a `B` member function is stored in `A`.

Comment: It should be noted that in order to call a member function pointer, an instance of the class is needed to invoke the function on, e.g. `B b; (b.*ptr)();` or `B b; std::invoke(ptr, b, args...);`

Comment: I will also note that this `typedef` syntax is now deprecated in preference for `using`, and that in this case you could also use a `std::function<void()>` if you need less coupling between the two types.

Comment: @DX-MON Sure, I kept the same syntax as OP had to make the diff clear. I have the `using` syntax in the demo with a note.

Comment: @Ted many thanks for the reply and the demo. Would it be possible to update the demo to call B::funcB? This is not called atm.

Comment: @MohammedZiad I guess - but where? I don't think I removed any functionality from your original code. I just shifted it around a little.

Comment: @TedLyngmo if I add a function in class `A`, then how would I call `funptr` in this function so this would call `B::funcB`?

Comment: MohammedZiad I added a new demo. Note that I also added a pointer to a `B` in `A` like @MorningDewd mentioned.